# Accessing namespace script variable

Tags: scope, scoping, apl, lexical-scope, dyalog

Concider the following namespace script in Dyalog APL:

```
:Namespace Test

    x ← 0

    ∇ F
        ##.Test.x ← 1
    ∇

    ∇ G; x
        x ← 0
        F
    ∇          

:EndNamespace
```

If I run *Test.G* and then *Test.x*, I get the output zero. How come? How do I set *Test.x* in *Test.F*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tradfns (traditional functions using `∇` and a header, etc.) use [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping), which means that they "see" the environment of the place they are called from. (This is in contrast to dfns which use [lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping); they see environment in which they were defined.) See [the documentation](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/Defined%20Functions%20and%20Operators/DynamicFunctions/Static%20Name%20Scope.htm) for details.

Now, when `G` calls `F`, while `x` is localised in `G`, the global `x` is invisible to `F` because the localisation in `G` shadows the global `x`.

Notice that `##.Test.` doesn't change which namespace we're working in. `x` is still shadowed.

If instead you had used dfns, you would see the behaviour you want:

```
:Namespace Test

    x ← 0

      F←{
          ##.Test.x←1
      }

      G←{
          x←0
          F ⍬
      }

:EndNamespace
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///38ovMTe1uCAxOVUhJLW4hItLAQgqFB61TVAwgHAUFNyAvGooGwSUlfVAavUqgOKGUPFamGJ3NMUgRQZIfDeFR71rEJqsXPNS4E74/x9srjtYCcQKAA)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To me this implies that a module with state should not use tradfns since there is no way to know if the intended variable is referenced. And if dfns is used instead we cannot use control structures. I also find it inconsistent that in your example, using dfns, F can access the global variable x without a namespace prefix, but if it writes to the same variable without prefix a new local variable is introduced.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Each module should be a separate namespace, in which case F will be called in its "home" and see its state variables. `F` can see its environment, but by default, dfns "auto-localise" upon assignment. You can prevent the auot-localisation by specifying a namespace path or using modified assignment.

Comment: In this example, yes, but a function which is a part of the module's interface is not called in its "home", it's called from the outside.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom That's fine, if you call a function that resides in a different namespace, it will see its own home environment, not that of the caller, due to its "current namespace".